# Remote Address Parameter in Zend_Http_Client

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-http-client

Am developing a public site that uses the Zend_Http_Client to access remote logic.Is there a property/way in the Client adapter that I could set the remote address of the user browsing the site?

Currently am using this workaround which combines both remote address and remote useragent.

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client();       
$client->setConfig(array(                       
    'useragent' => 'Get Remote Address'.'Get User Agent',       
));
```

Is there a specific property for remote address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From any Zend_Controller_Action method you can retrieve the user's remote address as follows:

```
$ip = $this->getRequest()->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

If you're not in a Controller, you can use the following assuming the Front Controller was used:

```
$ip = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getServer('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

And finally - these methods are just wrappers for the SERVER superglobal:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Substitute REMOTE_ADDR with HTTP_USER_AGENT to get the user agent.

Comment: That I already have.The issue is how to pass that value IN the Zend_Http_Client adapter so that on the server I can comfortably retrieve the remote address in the REMOTE_ADDR variable instead of having the value in the HTTP_USER_AGENT variable.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the question! This is not possible with PHP.